# Validate Multiple controls at once with most optimized way in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple methods which validates and return Boolean value a control. what can be best way to write the logic so that it validates and highlights all invalid controls, doesn't submit form to server and in future I have to make least code change if new control is added.

> Aprroach 1.  And ,  OR logic operator will not give correct result

```
if ( (Method1(ctrl1) && Method2(ctrl2) && Method3(ctrl3)))
{  // not   submit to server }
  else    //submit the form
```

> Approach 2 -  still change in logic will require if new control is
>   added for validation

```
var valid1 = Method1(ctrl1);
var valid2 = Method1(ctrl2);
var valid3 = Method1(ctrl3);
if(va1id1 && va1id2 && va1id3)
  // not   submit to server 
  else 
    // submit to server
```

Comment: Javascript is not Java, nor is it C#. I highly recommend use learn the name of the language you're writing code in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an array called valid which contains the result of all validations.

```
  var valid = [];

  valid.push(Method1(ctrl1));
  ...

  var entry = valid.reduce(function(validity,state){
      return validity && state; //if any entry in the valid array is false the result will be false
  },true);

  if(entry){
  //do something
  }
  else{
  //do something else
  }
```

If a new validation check has to be added you have to add one line to the code though: `valid.push(Method1(ctrln));`

Answer (score 0):

The object oriented answer: have one class / object per "check". They all go into a list of some sort. The final checking works by iterating that list to call the same method there.

That only requires you to add a new class / object for each new check you need.